# Can the bicycles and cycling tags be combined?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I see the site has questions with the tag [bicycles](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bicycles) and the tag [cycling](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycling). Could these be turned into synonyms? Any objections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged [cycling](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycling) into [bicycles](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bicycles).

Comment: On behalf of all unicyclists, and our tricycle-loving brethren, I object! ;-)